# Given the prime factorization of a number, is there an efficient way of sorting all the factors?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

One way of sorting is to generate all the factors and then sort the list.  I was wondering if there was a more efficient way.  Given a number n = product of p<sub>i</sub><sup>j<sub>i</sub></sup>, if you sort the p<sub>i</sub> values then it is easy to find the first few factors.  We can assume that p<sub>1</sub> < p<sub>2</sub>...< p<sub>k</sub> . The smallest factor is 1, followed by p<sub>1</sub> and the smaller of p<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> and p<sub>2</sub>.  Is there an algorithm to continue is this way?  Note that it is only necessary to find the first half of the factors. Going in reverse direction from n, we get the factors n/1 > n/p<sub>1</sub> and so on.

Comment: A number must be huge that the effort necessary to sort the factors is significant. Just use an efficient sort algorithm as quick sort. This should be good enough for pratical purposes.

Comment: You can do an on-the-fly mergesort while you generate the factors. So if you have a new prime power factor $p^k$, and $(x_1, x_2,...,x_k)$ are the previously discovered factors in sorted order, then you have to merge the $k+1$ lists $(p^ix_1, p^ix_2,...,p^ix_k)$ together where $0\le i \le k$. This should be faster than a full sort since each of these lists is already sorted.

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30181351/10427899

Comment: I think I see what you are saying.  You can do merge sorts by creating and merging the factors for one new prime at a time, making use of the fact that ascending powers of a given prime form an ascending sequence.  It may not matter what order the primes are chosen, which would make it unnecessary to first sort the primes. I will try to write a Python program that does this.  Thanks.